# Exchange 2007 and 2010: Weekly report of internal email needed

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-2007, reporting

I have two Exchange mailbox servers.  One running 2007 the other 2010, both Standard edition.

I've looked at 3rd party solutions to get email statistics, and I'm sure they'll work fine.  I like MessageStats in particular.

But, I'm curious if there are any free tools or scripts (or even under $500) out there that can give me a weekly report of internal emails (sent/received without going through the SMTP connectors), for both versions/servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evan, thanks.

I found this powershell script over on Technet that does exactly what is needed for free.

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/bb94b422-eb9e-4c53-a454-f7da6ddfb5d6

Hope it helps others here.

And just in case the link dies in the future:

```
#mjolinor 
#02/24/2011 

#requires -version 2.0 

$today = get-date 
$rundate = $($today.adddays(-1)).toshortdatestring() 

$outfile_date = ([datetime]$rundate).tostring("yyyy_MM_dd") 
$outfile = "email_stats_" + $outfile_date + ".csv" 

$dl_stat_file = "DL_stats.csv" 

$accepted_domains = Get-AcceptedDomain |% {$_.domainname.domain} 
[regex]$dom_rgx = "`(?i)(?:" + (($accepted_domains |% {"@" + [regex]::escape($_)}) -join "|") + ")$" 

$mbx_servers = Get-ExchangeServer |? {$_.serverrole -match "Mailbox"}|% {$_.fqdn} 
[regex]$mbx_rgx = "`(?i)(?:" + (($mbx_servers |% {"@" + [regex]::escape($_)}) -join "|") + ")\>$" 

$msgid_rgx = "^\<.+@.+\..+\>$" 

$hts = get-exchangeserver |? {$_.serverrole -match "hubtransport"} |% {$_.name} 

$exch_addrs = @{} 

$msgrec = @{} 
$bytesrec = @{} 

$msgrec_exch = @{} 
$bytesrec_exch = @{} 

$msgrec_smtpext = @{} 
$bytesrec_smtpext = @{} 

$total_msgsent = @{} 
$total_bytessent = @{} 
$unique_msgsent = @{} 
$unique_bytessent = @{} 

$total_msgsent_exch = @{} 
$total_bytessent_exch = @{} 
$unique_msgsent_exch = @{} 
$unique_bytessent_exch = @{} 

$total_msgsent_smtpext = @{} 
$total_bytessent_smtpext = @{} 
$unique_msgsent_smtpext=@{} 
$unique_bytessent_smtpext = @{} 

$dl = @{} 


$obj_table = { 
@" 
Date = $rundate 
User = $($address.split("@")[0]) 
Domain = $($address.split("@")[1]) 
Sent Total = $(0 + $total_msgsent[$address]) 
Sent MB Total = $("{0:F2}" -f $($total_bytessent[$address]/1mb)) 
Received Total = $(0 + $msgrec[$address]) 
Received MB Total = $("{0:F2}" -f $($bytesrec[$address]/1mb)) 
Sent Internal = $(0 + $total_msgsent_exch[$address]) 
Sent Internal MB = $("{0:F2}" -f $($total_bytessent_exch[$address]/1mb)) 
Sent External = $(0 + $total_msgsent_smtpext[$address]) 
Sent External MB = $("{0:F2}" -f $($total_bytessent_smtpext[$address]/1mb)) 
Received Internal = $(0 + $msgrec_exch[$address]) 
Received Internal MB = $("{0:F2}" -f $($bytesrec_exch[$address]/1mb)) 
Received External = $(0 + $msgrec_smtpext[$address]) 
Received External MB = $("{0:F2}" -f $($bytesrec_smtpext[$address]/1mb)) 
Sent Unique Total = $(0 + $unique_msgsent[$address]) 
Sent Unique MB Total = $("{0:F2}" -f $($unique_bytessent[$address]/1mb)) 
Sent Internal Unique  = $(0 + $unique_msgsent_exch[$address])  
Sent Internal Unique MB = $("{0:F2}" -f $($unique_bytessent_exch[$address]/1mb)) 
Sent External  Unique = $(0 + $unique_msgsent_smtpext[$address]) 
Sent External Unique MB = $("{0:F2}" -f $($unique_bytessent_smtpext[$address]/1mb)) 
"@ 
} 

$props = $obj_table.ToString().Split("`n")|% {if ($_ -match "(.+)="){$matches[1].trim()}} 

$stat_recs = @() 

function time_pipeline { 
param ($increment  = 1000) 
begin{$i=0;$timer = [diagnostics.stopwatch]::startnew()} 
process { 
    $i++ 
    if (!($i % $increment)){Write-host “`rProcessed $i in $($timer.elapsed.totalseconds) seconds” -nonewline} 
    $_ 
    } 
end { 
    write-host “`rProcessed $i log records in $($timer.elapsed.totalseconds) seconds” 
    Write-Host "   Average rate: $([int]($i/$timer.elapsed.totalseconds)) log recs/sec." 
    } 
} 

foreach ($ht in $hts){ 

    Write-Host "`nStarted processing $ht" 

    get-messagetrackinglog -Server $ht -Start "$rundate" -End "$rundate 11:59:59 PM" -resultsize unlimited | 
    time_pipeline |%{ 


    if ($_.eventid -eq "DELIVER" -and $_.source -eq "STOREDRIVER"){ 

        if ($_.messageid -match $mbx_rgx -and $_.sender -match $dom_rgx) { 

            $total_msgsent[$_.sender] += $_.recipientcount 
            $total_bytessent[$_.sender] += ($_.recipientcount * $_.totalbytes) 
            $total_msgsent_exch[$_.sender] += $_.recipientcount 
            $total_bytessent_exch[$_.sender] += ($_.totalbytes * $_.recipientcount) 

            foreach ($rcpt in $_.recipients){ 
            $exch_addrs[$rcpt] ++ 
            $msgrec[$rcpt] ++ 
            $bytesrec[$rcpt] += $_.totalbytes 
            $msgrec_exch[$rcpt] ++ 
            $bytesrec_exch[$rcpt] += $_.totalbytes 
            } 

        } 

        else { 
            if ($_messageid -match $messageid_rgx){ 
                    foreach ($rcpt in $_.recipients){ 
                        $msgrec[$rcpt] ++ 
                        $bytesrec[$rcpt] += $_.totalbytes 
                        $msgrec_smtpext[$rcpt] ++ 
                        $bytesrec_smtpext[$rcpt] += $_.totalbytes 
                    } 
                } 

            } 

    } 


    if ($_.eventid -eq "RECEIVE" -and $_.source -eq "STOREDRIVER"){ 
        $exch_addrs[$_.sender] ++ 
        $unique_msgsent[$_.sender] ++ 
        $unique_bytessent[$_.sender] += $_.totalbytes 

            if ($_.recipients -match $dom_rgx){ 
                $unique_msgsent_exch[$_.sender] ++ 
                $unique_bytessent_exch[$_.sender] += $_.totalbytes 
                } 

            if ($_.recipients -notmatch $dom_rgx){ 
                $ext_count = ($_.recipients -notmatch $dom_rgx).count 
                $unique_msgsent_smtpext[$_.sender] ++ 
                $unique_bytessent_smtpext[$_.sender] += $_.totalbytes 
                $total_msgsent[$_.sender] += $ext_count 
                $total_bytessent[$_.sender] += ($ext_count * $_.totalbytes) 
                $total_msgsent_smtpext[$_.sender] += $ext_count 
                 $total_bytessent_smtpext[$_.sender] += ($ext_count * $_.totalbytes) 
                } 


        } 

    if ($_.eventid -eq "expand"){ 
        $dl[$_.relatedrecipientaddress] ++ 
        } 
    }      

} 

foreach ($address in $exch_addrs.keys){ 

$stat_rec = (new-object psobject -property (ConvertFrom-StringData (&$obj_table))) 
$stat_recs += $stat_rec | select $props 
} 

$stat_recs | export-csv $outfile -notype  

if (Test-Path $dl_stat_file){ 
    $DL_stats = Import-Csv $dl_stat_file 
    $dl_list = $dl_stats |% {$_.address} 
    } 

else { 
    $dl_list = @() 
    $DL_stats = @() 
    } 


$DL_stats |% { 
    if ($dl[$_.address]){ 
        if ([datetime]$_.lastused -le [datetime]$rundate){  
            $_.used = [int]$_.used + [int]$dl[$_.address] 
            $_.lastused = $rundate 
            } 
        } 
} 

$dl.keys |% { 
    if ($dl_list -notcontains $_){ 
        $new_rec = "" | select Address,Used,Since,LastUsed 
        $new_rec.address = $_ 
        $new_rec.used = $dl[$_] 
        $new_rec.Since = $rundate 
        $new_rec.lastused = $rundate 
        $dl_stats += @($new_rec) 
    } 
} 

$dl_stats | Export-Csv $dl_stat_file -NoTypeInformation -force 


Write-Host "`nRun time was $(((get-date) - $today).totalseconds) seconds." 
Write-Host "Email stats file is $outfile" 
Write-Host "DL usage stats file is $dl_stat_file" 


#Contact information 
#[string](0..33|%{[char][int](46+("686552495351636652556262185355647068516270555358646562655775 0645570").substring(($_*2),2))})-replace " "
```

Comment: BTW, I also manipulated line 101 and the variables for Rundate as well as added additional variables for the output so that everything formats correctly and shows the last 7 days instead of the last day.  Some of that info is found on that URL I posted but if you want to know more just post here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The [message tracking logs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc539064.aspx) are ASCII text files and fairly easy to parse. If you're comfortable writing scripts you could probably code something quick-and-dirty that would give you what you want. With the right header definition [Microsoft LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24659) could probably do what you want, too.